# Multiplying two dataframes to create a time series

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, one is of portfolio weights where each row is a portfolio and the other is a list of security returns by date, in other words a return time series for each security. Both have the same columns i.e. the securities, and in the same order.

I would like to multiply the securities dataframe by each row of the portfolios dataframe and create a new dataframe for each portfolio based on the multiplied value i.e. weight * value by date. Then sum each column in the new dataframe and use that to create a portfolio time series.

I've tried to find solutions for this, as in multiplying one by the other in a loop, but I've had no success.

This is an example of what I've tested.

```
#for loop to create time series for tested portfolios

x = 0

portfolios_time_series = pd.DataFrame()

for x in portfolios_df:
    portfolio_underlying_returns = security_returns_df.multiply(portfolios_df.iloc[x]) 
    portfolios_time_series = portfolios_time_series.append(portfolio_underlying_returns.sum(axis=1))
```

So if portfolios is like this:

[image: portfolios_df]

And securities look like this:

[image: security_returns]

Then two new dataframes should be created in a loop (if a loop is the best solution) like these:

[image: underlying dataframes]

And then a final time series dataframe for the portfolios should be like this:

[image: final dataframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy broadcast to avoid using loop with vectorized operations:

```
A = df1.fillna(0).values  # portfolios
B = df2.fillna(0).values  # securities
r = (A[:, None] * B).sum(axis=2).T

out = pd.DataFrame(r, index=df2.index, columns=df1.index)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                0       1
13/03/23  0.01775  0.0063
14/03/23  0.01475  0.0033
```